# How to set up libusb dependency with CMake?

Tags: cmake, libusb

I am trying to develop an application using GreatScottGadget's Ubertooth One. To start, I need to be able to use the `libusb` library. I'm working with Ubuntu 20.04.

I have a simple `CMakeLists.txt` file that sets the module path to a path in my project that contains all the `Find*.cmake` files that I stole from the `ubertooth` repository [here](https://github.com/greatscottgadgets/ubertooth). I include `libusb` like so:

```
find_package(USB1 REQUIRED)
```

When I run CMake, this is the error I get:

```
Could not find package configuration file provided by "USB1" with any of the following names:

  USB1Config.cmake
  usb1-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "USB1" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"USB1_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files. If "USB1"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure that it has been
installed.
```

As far as I can tell, I have `libusb` already installed. `apt list --installed | grep libusb` shows `libusb-1.0.0-dev/focal,now 2:1.0.23-2build1 amd64 [installed]` (among others). I can see the shared object in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

```
$ ls /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu | grep libusb
libusb-0.1.so.4
libusb-0.1.so.4.4.4
libusb-1.0.a
libusb-1.0.so
libusb-1.0.so.0
libusb-1.0.so.0.2.0
libusbmuxd.so.6
libusbmuxd.so.6.0.0
```

Additionally, I can build the host code provided in the `ubertooth` repository just fine. In the CMake output, I see the following:

```
-- Checking for module 'libusb-1.0'
--   Found libusb-1.0, version 1.0.23
-- Found LIBUSB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so
```

Looking through the `ubertooth` repository, I don't see anything special they are doing to find the package. The `host` project adds `libubertooth` as a subdirectory, in in its [`CMakeLists.txt`](https://github.com/greatscottgadgets/ubertooth/blob/master/host/libubertooth/src/CMakeLists.txt), it uses the same method I have to find the library. I'm not seeing any other differences.

Maybe I'm misunderstanding and the `libubertooth` subdirectory *isn't* where the library is being found. Maybe there's some global config that I'm not setting. I haven't managed to find whatever it is.

I checked the `libusb` [homepage](https://libusb.info/) and downloaded the source, but I didn't find any `USB1Config.cmake` files, so I'm not sure how this is supposed to work.

What am I missing to be able to find the library and use it in my project?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you don't have a `FindUSB1.cmake` in you project. You can find it on [ubertooth/host/cmake/modules/FindUSB1.cmake](https://github.com/greatscottgadgets/ubertooth/blob/d1feeccbd2fba266695a0052caab872ca5bcc263/host/cmake/modules/FindUSB1.cmake).

BTW, don't use *stole*, you can find ubertooth's [license](https://github.com/greatscottgadgets/ubertooth/blob/d1feeccbd2fba266695a0052caab872ca5bcc263/COPYING), it's GPL-2.0

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure if that's my problem though. I do have that file in my project/cmake/modules directory, and I am using `FindUBERTOOTH.cmake` and that works. Therefore I think that CMake is finding my modules directory and using it, but either it isn't able to use `FindUSB1.cmake` for some reason, or I have a different problem.